# NullPointerException when try to capture imagem from webcam

Tags: java

I got an error in my line 508 where I have this code

`buf = fgc.grabFrame();`

**CODE:**

```
startC.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {           
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {                   
                  // Grab a frame   
                  FrameGrabbingControl fgc = (FrameGrabbingControl) 
                  player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");    
                  buf = fgc.grabFrame();       

              // Convert it to an image 
              BufferToImage btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat()); 
              img = btoi.createImage(buf);             

                  // show the image 
                  //imgpanel.setImage(img);       

                  // save image 
                  try {
                    saveJPG(img,"c:\\test.jpg");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
}):
```

**STACK:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.colorfulwolf.webcamapplet.WebcamApplet$6.actionPerformed(WebcamApplet.java:508)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

What's going wrong with this line ?

Comment: Have you instantiated `player`?

Comment: yes. `public static Player player = null; `

Comment: That'll be your problem then!

Comment: @Lucas_Santos instantiating and initializing is two different things. You've initialized the variable to a null value, instantiating means to create an instance of a class and put it in the variable.

Comment: @SimonAndréForsberg thanks for the explanation, this will be helpfull, to not make this same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign `player` to an instance:

```
public static Player player = new Player();
```

Comment: @Lucas_Santos You need to **instantiate** the fgc variable too. Whatever type that is. It should NOT have a null value. Setting a null value to it and then trying to use it is like asking for trouble.

Comment: and now I have `public Buffer buf = new Buffer();  `

Comment: Are you getting a `NullPointerException` for `buf = fgc.grabFrame()` now?

Comment: @Reimeus, sorry, resolved! =) it was my mistake using the Interface.