# NullPointerException when attempting to save webcam image from Java Applet

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NullPointerException when try to capture imagem from webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12571290/nullpointerexception-when-try-to-capture-imagem-from-webcam)

I saw this good [webcam applet](http://webcamapplet.sourceforge.net/how.html) but i'm beginner with java, and I'm trying just put another `JButton` called `Capture` that will take a picture through the webcam and save in a specific path.

**CODE OF MY CAPTURE BUTTON**

```
startC.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {           
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {               
                  // Grab a frame                 
                 FrameGrabbingControl fgc = new FrameGrabbingControl() {

                        @Override
                        public Component getControlComponent() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Buffer grabFrame() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }
                    };  
                  player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");    
                  buf = fgc.grabFrame();                  

                  // Convert it to an image               
                  BufferToImage btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
                  img = btoi.createImage(buf);       

                  // show the image 
                  //imgpanel.setImage(img);       

                  // save image 
                  try {
                    saveJPG(img,"c:\\test.jpg");
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

**SAVE JPG METHOD**

```
      public static void saveJPG(Image img, String s) throws IOException    
      {       
        BufferedImage bi = new BufferedImage(img.getWidth(null), img.getHeight(null), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);      
        File outputfile = new File("C:\\saved.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(bi, "png", outputfile);
}
```

**ERROR**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.colorfulwolf.webcamapplet.WebcamApplet$6.actionPerformed(WebcamApplet.java:524)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

In my line 524 I have the code

```
BufferToImage btoi = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat)buf.getFormat());
```

**FGC declaration**

```
FrameGrabbingControl fgc = new FrameGrabbingControl() {                     
                        @Override
                        public Component getControlComponent() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public Buffer grabFrame() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            return null;
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: Looks like `buf` is not instantiated.

Comment: I think I instantiate everybody. `public static Player player = new Player()`
`public Buffer buf = new Buffer();`
`public Image img = new Image()`

Comment: Is it the same NullPointerException as in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12571290/645270) question you posted? (i.e. possible duplicate)

Comment: Yes but, I tryied to instantiate this one, or make different, but without success, and googling it, I saw some samples that exactly equals.

Comment: Check what is being returned back from `fgc.grabFrame()`. Possibly more setup to be done.

Comment: `fgc` return the value "WebcamApplet$5$1 (id = 105). `buf` return `null`. I don't understand. if `fgc` has a value, so `buf` should return something different than `null` :

Comment: Looking better, in the `fgc` instance, I have the `grabFrame` that return `null`. Is that the problem ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application is throw a NullPointerException because you try to invoke a method on a null object, `buf`.

Even though you declare `buf = fgc.grabFrame();`, your `buf` object is null because `fgc.grabFrame()` is returning null.

```
@Override
public Buffer grabFrame() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
```

To fix the issue, you can return `new Buffer()` instead of `null` in your `fgc.grabFrame()` implementation.